# How to return value from vb script to command variable?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I have a simple vb script (file name: wiguid.vbs) that generates a new Guid.

```
set obj = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")  
WScript.Echo obj.GUID
```

I need to call this script from a cmd batch file, store new guid in a command parameter, and pass that variable to other vb scripts.
But I fail to store value generated in a vbscript to a command parameter.

Something like:

```
cscript wiguid.vbs 
set NewGuid = '??Should get value from above script call'
cscript OtherVbScript.vbs "SET Value='%NewGuid%'"
```

I tried different search combinations but couldn't get any way to achieve that.

Any pointers/suggestions would be of help!
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo wiguid.vbs') do set "newGUID=%%a"
    echo new guid = %newGUID%

    endlocal
```

Without using a temporary file, `for /f` is the usual way of assigning a value to a variable from the output of the execution of a command.

It just runs the indicated command and for each of the lines in the output, the code in the `do` clause is executed. The replaceable parameter (the `%%a`) of the `for` command will hold all or part of the line. See `for /?` for a complete reference

Comment: Thanks for the //nologo argument!  Very helpful.